# Nested property path in Projections.property()

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the following code:

```
Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Term.class);
c.setProjection(
        Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("id"))
                .add(Projections.property("qualifier"))
                .add(Projections.property("preferred"))
                .add(Projections.property("terminology.definition"))
);
c.list();
```

but Hibernate chokes on `terminology.definition` with an exception
    org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: terminology.definition of: net.***.Term

despite the fact that there is a property in `Term`:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "term")
public Terminology getTerminology() { return terminology; }
```

and `Terminology` has a `@Basic` property named `definition`. I can fix it with an stupid-looking alias:

```
session.createCriteria(Term.class).createAlias("terminology", "terminology")
```

but it is undesirable.

Comment: you need your stupid-looking alias because hibernate use it to join your tables. _Projections_ is like the select clause of a query, so you only say in your code to project terminology property that it's not in your entity _Term_ as a property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty standard due to the way selects are being done.
Terminology is mostly like brought in through a join on the SQL side, but in terms of the query, you have to define an alias in order to be able to access a joined table.

In fact, if you look at the JavaDocs for `Criteria` class, there's even an example of it:

You may navigate associations using `createAlias()` or `createCriteria()`.

```
 List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
     .createCriteria("kittens")
         .add( Restrictions.like("name", "Iz%") )
     .list();

 List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
     .createAlias("kittens", "kit")
     .add( Restrictions.like("kit.name", "Iz%") )
     .list();
```

You'll notice you can either use an alias and the `.` notation, or you can use `createCriteria` with a straight property name.

However, this example is for the where clause. Not 100% how it would play out for the projections (i.e., if you can have subcriteria with projections).  I'd just stick to the alias approach you already have.